# How do you mock equality?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, kotlin, mockito, hamcrest

Let's say I have an interface

```
interface IFoo{
    val foo:String
}
```

and I want to create classes that are equal IFF their `foo` string matches.

Simple example:

```
class A(override val foo:String):IFoo{
    val somethingIrrelevant = "bar"

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        return if(other is IFoo) foo == other.foo else false
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return Objects.hash(foo)
    }
}
```

Seems relatively straightforward, yet this test case:

```
@Test
fun mockingEquality(){
    //given
    val a = A("alpha")
    val b = A("alpha")

    assertThat(a,`is`(b)) //succeeds


    //when
    val c = mock(A::class.java)
    whenever(c.foo).thenReturn("alpha")

    //then
    assertThat(c, `is`(a)) //fails
}
```

fails with

```
Expected: is <A@589b17d>
     but: was <Mock for A, hashCode: 263885523>
```

Why is that?
And **how do I correctly mock the `A` class for this test to succeed?**

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that when you create a mock, that object has no behavior unless you explicitly mock it. That includes your `equals` and `hashCode` methods.

With your example, one 'fix' would be to mock the `equals` and `hashCode` methods, but obviously that doesn't add any value to your test. Trivially, you could invert your assertion (`assertThat(a, is(c))`) which happens to work because the end result will be `a.equals(c)`, and `a` is a real instance of class `A` instead of a mock and has the `.foo` property mock.

I suspect your examples are just overly simplified, but in those given cases you should prefer to just create a real instance instead of mocking (e.g. `val c = A("alpha")` rather than `mock(A::class.java)`).

Some other approaches here could be:

Another approach would be to use a spy if you can acquire a real instance of the class. For example:

```
val c = spy(A("other value"))
doReturn("mock value").whenever(c).foo
```

But you can see in [documentation](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.24.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doCallRealMethod--) that these ways of partially mocking a class are not the recommended approach.

Comment: Is there a way to tell the mock to run the methods `equals` and `hashCode` as usual just with the mocked value? Like "return default values EXCEPT for these methods"? (And yes, this is the simplest I could break the issue down to.)

Comment: Edited the answer to give some more options for that

Comment: 2 fails with

``you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.``

Comment: Ah good catch, didn't realize there was that limitation. Updated to remove that suggestion.